# Web scraping in R by first navigating through a JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rselenium

I looked up various questions and answers but unfortunately none of the problems I found dealt with a case that is similar to mine. In a typical question, the JavaScript table builds up directly when the website is loaded. In my case, however, I first have to navigate through the JavaScript module and select several criteria before I get the sought-after result.

This is my case: I have to scrape the exchange rates for various currencies from this website [www.globocambio.co](https://www.globocambio.co/en/home). To do that, I have (1) to navigate to *“I WANT COLOMBIAN PESO”*, (2) select the currency (e.g., *“Chilean Peso”*), (3) and the collection destination (e.g., *“El Dorado International Airport”*). Only then the respective exchange rate is being loaded. See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J67CF.jpg) for illustration. I marked the three selection steps red. Green is the data point that I want to scrape for different currencies.

I am not very familiar with JavaScript but I tried to understand what is going on. Here is what I found out:

1. Using Chrome DevTools, I investigated the Network activity when loading an exchange rate. There is an XHR called “GetPrice” that requests the price using this URL: `https://reservations.globocambio.co/DesktopModules/GlobalExchange/API/Widget/GetPrice` and using the following Form Data 
   `ISOAOrigen=CLP&cantidadOrigen=9000&ISOADestino=COP&cantidadDestino=0&centerId=27&operationType=OperationTypesBuying`
2. I understand that the Form Data contains the information that I initially selected manually:

   1. `operationType=OperationTypesBuying`: this is the *“I WANT COLOMBIAN PESO”* option
   2. `ISOAOrigen=CLP`: this is the *“Chilean Peso”*
   3. `centerId=27`: this is the *“El Dorado International Airport”*
3. The server responds to my request with the following information:

   `{“MonedaOrigen":{"ISOA":"CLP","Nombre":null,"Margen":0.1630000000,"Tramo":0.0,"Fixing":2.9000000000},"CantidadOrigen":9000.00,"MonedaDestino":{"ISOA":"COP","Nombre":null,"Margen":0.0,"Tramo":0.0,"Fixing":0.0},"CantidadDestino":21845.70,"TipoCambio":2.42730000000000000000,"MargenOrigen":0.0,"TramoOrigen":0.0,"FixingOrigen":0.0,"MargenDestino":0.0,"TramoDestino":0.0,"FixingDestino":0.0,"IdCentro":"27","Comision":null,"ComisionTramoSuperior":null,"ComisionAplicada":{"CodigoMoneda":null,"CodigoTipoMoneda":0,"ComisionFija":0.0,"ComisionVariable":0.0,"TramoInicio":0.0,"TramoFin":null,"Orden”:0}}`
4. From this response, `"TipoCambio":2.42730000000000000000` is then being written on the website using this line of HTML code: `<span id="spTipoCambioCompra">2.427300</span>`
5. This means that `"TipoCambio"` is the value that I am looking for.

So, I have to communicate somehow via R with the server using the Form Data as input variables. Can anyone tell me how to do this? 
I mean, understand that I have to combine the URL `https://reservations.globocambio.co/DesktopModules/GlobalExchange/API/Widget/GetPrice` with the Form Data “`ISOAOrigen=CLP&cantidadOrigen=9000&ISOADestino=COP&cantidadDestino=0&centerId=27&operationType=OperationTypesBuying`” somehow but I do not know how it works..

Any help will be appreciated!

### **Update:**

I still have no idea how to solve the above issue, yet. However, I try to approach it with small steps.
Using RSelenium, I am currently trying to find out how to click on the option *“I WANT COLOMBIAN PESO”*. My idea was to use the following code:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                 port = 4445L,
                                 browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.globocambio.co/en/home")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "tabCompra") #What is wrong here?
webElem$clickElement() # Click on "I WANT COLOMBIAN PESO"
```

But I get an error message after executing `webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "tabCompra")`:

> Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#tabCompra"} 
>     (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   ...
>   Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
>        Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
>        class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
>        Further Details: run errorDetails method

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using selenium in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '/your_path/geckodriver')

driver.get("https://www.globocambio.co/en/")
driver.switch_to.frame("iframeWidget");

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('tabCompra')
elem.click()

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('inputddlMonedaOrigenCompra')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys(Keys.CLEAR)
elem.send_keys("Chilean Peso")
elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id('info-change-compra')
print(elem.text)
```